# Need support to fix the following XML Parser issue. I tried with xpath & var_dump but it didn't worked out

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

```
    <root>
    <code>
    <command>AAA BBB CCC <cmd>DDD</cmd> EEE</command>
    </code>
    </root>
```

**Excepted Output:**

```
**AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE**
```

**Output**

```
**AAA BBB CCC EEE DDD**
```

Comment: Can you show the code which produces the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
$string = " <root>
    <code>
    <command>AAA BBB CCC <cmd>DDD</cmd> EEE</command>
    </code>
    </root>
";                                                                       
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$targets = array();

$results = $xpath->query('//command//text()');
foreach ($results as $result)
{   
    array_push($targets, trim($result->nodeValue) ." ");
}
foreach($targets as $target)
{
 echo $target;        
}
```

Output:

```
AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the code it is difficult to say what your error is. So here is an example hot to do it with DOM+Xpath:

```
$xmlString = <<<'XML'
<root>
    <code>
        <command>AAA BBB CCC <cmd>DDD</cmd> EEE</command>
    </code>
</root>
XML;
                                                                     
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(//command)')
);
```

Output:

```
string(19) "AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE"
```

`//command` fetches any `command` element node in the document. `string(//command)` casts the first found element into a string - it returns the text content of the node.

If you have multiple `command` elements you can iterate the them and read the `$textContent` property.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//command') as $command) {
    var_dump($command->textContent);
}
```